Codeigniter 4.0 Model issue
I am new to the codeigniter 4.0 framework and been trying to upgrade my old code from 3.0 to 4.0 and in the meantime learn the new framework. Currently I am running into an issue which I cannot explain is quite frustrating.
I've got a Controller called Account.php located in the App\Controllers directory.
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\AccountModel;

class Account extends BaseController
{

    private $accountModel;
    private $validation;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Load the Account_model globally in the constructor        
        $this->accountModel = new AccountModel();
        $this->validation = \Config\Services::validation();
    }

    public function signup_process()
    {
        // Set validation rules
        $this->validation->setRules([
            'username'          => 'required|max_length[50]',
            'email'             => 'required|valid_email|max_length[250]',
            'firstname'         => 'required|max_length[50]',
            'lastname'          => 'required|max_length[50]',
            'birthday'          => 'required|valid_date',
            'discord'           => 'max_length[50]',
        ]);

        // Validation failed, redirect back to the form with validation errors
        if (!$this->validation->withRequest($this->request)->run()) {            
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('errors', $this->validation->getErrors());
        
        } 
        // If validation passes, proceed with form processing
        else 
        {
            // Access form data
            $request = service('request');
            $arrUser['username']    = $request->getPost('username');
            $arrUser['email']       = $request->getPost('email');
            $arrUser['firstname']   = $request->getPost('firstname');
            $arrUser['lastname']    = $request->getPost('lastname');
            $arrUser['birthday']    = $request->getPost('birthday');
            $arrUser['discord']     = $request->getPost('discord');

            // Insert user data into the database using the model
            $this->accountModel->insert_user($arrUser);

            return redirect()->to('/account/signup-done');
        }
        
    }
}


And I am trying to call a function in my AccountModel.php file located in the App\Models directory
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class AccountModel extends Model
{
    public function insert_user($arrUser) 
    {
        print_r($arrUser);
    }
}


As soon as I turn on the code $this->accountModel = new AccountModel();, I am greeted with the default Codeigniter error message
Whoops!
We seem to have hit a snag. Please try again later...
I've tried looking through the documentation of the framework, but can't find a clear explanation what might be going wrong.

You're simply missing a terminating semicolon in your model on line: print_r($arrUser) PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a semicolon at the end of each statement.

Put your .env ENVIRONMENT constant to DEVELOPMENT so you will get the full error stack. The « Whoops » page is the one displayed when environment is set to PRODUCTION.

Even though I missed the semicolon, this wasn't the reason it broke.
I've set the variabale to .env file to development, however I am still receiving the error "Whoops!".
Perhaps something is wrong with my Database setup because I am testing localy via (debug) Visual Studio Code instead of on a server?

I've got a hunch it's because of the name space in the controller, had the same issue with making a new empty object via new stdClass. Normally I would write "= new stdClass;" but apparently it should be "= new \stdClass;"

Why don't you just enable error logging in your .env file using logger.threshold = 4 and viewing the date-time stamped logs under writable/logs? Otherwise, your question is incomplete as it lacks debugging details. I.e. a proper error stack trace.

After figuring out that Codeigniter collects error logs, I've found that my local php didn't have mysqli enabled in the php.ini file. I've enabled it, and now my code runs as expected.
